# How to route this in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is my first ASP MVC project so I'm not sure how to do this.

I have a section called Admin, which has an Admin controller. I'm using this for just an index page.

In the Admin section, there are different sections. Let's say Company and Line Of Business

I want to handle everything for those in their own CompanyController and LineOfBusinessController

I want the routes to be prefixed with Admin though ie. Admin/Company, Admin/Company/Add

I have achieved this by adding a route before the Default route that is this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem is now all my routes choose this one over the default, meaning everything else becomes Admin/Section ie Admin/Home etc.....

I tried using Html.RouteLink instead of ActionLink and the URL's were formatted correctly, but when I go to Admin/Company it can't find because it assumes Company is in AdminController

How can I route this properly?

EDIT

Here are my routes, and then my links

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );            
    }
```

Links

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, ViewBag.SelectedNav == "Home" ? new { @class = "active" } : null)</li>
```

The link ends up /Admin/Home

UPDATE

Did not mark an answer here as I ended up exploring, and ultimately using Areas. It was suggested in the one answer, but the rest of the answer is not correct so I did not want to mislead anyone. Thanks for the Area suggestion however

Answer (score 0):

Have the generic routing below your specific one. The order of routing definition is important. When MVC finds a matching route for a request, it won't process the rest.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Admin",
            url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", 
                                               id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                       id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Also it is better for your to use **Areas** in this scenario. It is a better approach when you want to [structure](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/) your app in to different sections like Admin / Normal user etc..

Comment: I do have this already, but the other routes are choosing the Admin route instead of the generic route...I figured this would just work this way but it's not

Comment: do you have that link placed inside some views belongs to your admin area ?

Comment: No, it is a shared partial for the main nav

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what the link behavior should be, the best thing I can suggest is to debug your routes and see which route is handling which URL's.

1) Go into Visual Studio and install the [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

> PM> Install-Package routedebugger

2) Add some code to your global file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

3) Run your site and request your questionable links.

4) Review your results and modify accordingly

---

Edit: it appears as though [RouteDebugger v2](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx) is now [RouteMagic](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx)

> PM> Install-Package RouteMagic

And you can find the source code on [github](https://github.com/haacked/routemagic)

Comment: I've installed the routedebugger....it does not function this way for me. Maybe as I'm using MVC 4 on VS2012?
RouteDebug only has:
DebugHttpHandler, DebugRoute, DebugRouteHandler, PreApplicationStart, and RouteDebuggerHttpModule....there is no RouteDebugger property

Comment: Probably want to use DebugRoute. Phil's blog post is a little older, and there have been updates to the Nuget Package...

Comment: How can I write an equivalent of RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes); using DebugRoute? EDIT: nvm it does it automatically

Comment: Does this then answer your question? I've updated the answer to be a little more relevant.